# From R or RStudio, how to I delete a program-association with 'file.show' via a 'pager'

Tags: r, windows-10, rstudio, pager

In R I executed a 'file.show' code with a "pager" function, looking for a way to show a fasta file (my first foray into R; and any programming). I checked the box; "always use program x" with the file. Program x couldn't display the file type, but now each time I execute the code it defaults straight to program x. How can I undo this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the original file from its directory through windows, with another program. At the same time check the 'always open with this app' box. When you re-run the code in RStudio, "file.show" should now open with the associated program..